# Eigencircles of n x n matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control

An eigenvalue of a 2 x 2 matrix satisfies the equation

$$  \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y  \end{array}\right) = \lambda \left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)   $$

[Graham Farr](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~gfarr/) multiplies by the identity matrix.  It is still defines eigenvalues $(A - \lambda I ) \vec{x} = 0$.

$$  \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y  \end{array}\right) =  \left(\begin{array}{cc} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)   $$

He embeds the complex numbers into the space of 2 x 2 matrices and asks for vectors which are rotated + dilated the matrix.

$$  \left(\begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y  \end{array}\right) =  \left(\begin{array}{cc} \lambda & \mu \\ -\mu & \lambda \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right)   $$

The characteristic equation is defines a circle in $\mu,\lambda$.  This *[eigencircle](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~gfarr/research/slides/Farr-eigentalk.pdf)* is not really a fixed circle in the plane, but a collection of "characteristic" pairs of values forming a circle of values $(\mu,\nu) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

\[  \left| \begin{array}{cc} a - \lambda & b - \mu \\ c + \mu & d - \lambda \end{array} \right| = 0 \]

Farr made an [applet demonstrating these calculations](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~gfarr/research/eigencircles.html) and uses the eigencircles for easy demonstrations of relations between the eigenvectors, sign of the determinant, etc.

---

Can you have eigencircles in more than two dimensions?  I suppose you can ask for two basis vectors $v_1, v_2$ such that $Av_1 = \lambda v_1 + \mu v_2 $ and $Av_2 = - \mu v_1 + \lambda v_2$.  It also seems 2 x 2 matrices are singling out not only two directions, but a whole circle's worth of vectors.

Is there a correct higher-dimensional generalization of this?  Have these objects been studied under a different name?

Comment: Isn't an "eigencircle" just a way to study complex eigenvectors of a real matrix without extending scalars? 

Comment: Multiplication in the complex plane geometrically is rotation and scaling (by a positive constant). Maybe consider $SO(n) \times \mathbb{R}^+$, i.e. positively-scaled, special orthogonal matrices. Farr also mentions the use of quaternions toward the end of the article, though says this still applies to 2×2 matrices. Interesting stuff!

Comment: @Qiaochu Does a real matrix have a $SO(2)$ worth of complex eigenvalues? These are 2D invariant subspaces, where the matrix acts as an element of $\mathbb{C} = SO(2) \times \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @John: if $V$ is a 2D invariant subspace which contains no eigenvectors, then extending scalars to $\mathbb{C}$ you can find a pair of complex conjugate eigenvectors with complex eigenvalues which span $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$. In general just apply the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a PID to $\mathbb{R}[x]$. You get simple modules of the form $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x - r)$ (real eigenvectors) and $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2 + bx + c)$ for $b^2 - 4c < 0$ (pairs of complex eigenvectors). 

Comment: @Qiaochu Maybe these are 1D subspaces on which the action of the matrix is to rotate and dilate (i.e. multiply by $\lambda + \mu i$). A 2 x 2 matrix has exactly 2 complex eigenvalues and the pairs $(\lambda, \mu)$ can take a continuous range of values lying on a circle.  So they have different cardinalities.

Answer (score 5):

As I understand the problem it can be generalized. The $\small \lambda,\mu $-matrix can be seen as scaled rotation, and using  $ \small r^2 = \lambda^2 + \mu^2 $ we can, because the $\small \lambda,\mu$ - matrix is invertible and is the *left* factor on the rhs *(thus it is not really an eigenvalue analogon in my opinion)* we can differently rewrite your original equation as

$\qquad  \small \frac1{r^2} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & -\mu \\\ \mu & \lambda \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x \\\ y \end{bmatrix} \cdot 1 $

or 
$\qquad  \small \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\varphi) & -\sin(\varphi) \\\ \sin(\varphi) & \cos(\varphi) \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} x \\\ y \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} x \\\ y \end{bmatrix} \cdot r $

or
$\qquad \small (T \cdot A) \cdot X = X \cdot r$

where then the eigen-problem is
$\qquad \small \left\vert T \cdot A - r\cdot I  \right\vert = 0    $

The left factor ***T*** is simply a rotation-matrix and *r* the eigenvalue of the rotated matrix $\small T\cdot A$.

If this characterization of the $\small \lambda, \mu$-matrix is the interesting one (which I assume) it can then be generalized to more dimensions in the obvious way and the $\small \lambda ,\mu $'s have to be determined as scalings of the cos/sin-parameters by the eigenvalues of the multidimensionally rotated matrix.

---

[Update] Here is a picture of the construction according to my interpretation of the problem. I take some example-matrix ***A*** $\small  \begin{bmatrix} 12&24\\\  13&83 \end{bmatrix} $ then leftmultiply by the rotationmatrices of angles between *0* and $\small 2 \pi $. Each has then two eigenvalues $\small w_0 , w_1 $. The $\small \lambda,\mu$ -matrix is then $\small T \cdot w_0 $. Note, that the eigenvalues and thus the $\small \lambda,\mu$-matrix may become complex for some rotations. Then I plot the log of the absolute value of the two eigenvalues in different colors. Here is the picture:

[image] [<sup>(source)</sup>](http://go.helms-net.de/math/divers/mo/eigencircle.png)

Answer (score 2):

They are not exactly what you are looking for, but I think you should take a look at two-parameter eigenvalue problems. For instance check http://www.math.technion.ac.il/iic/ela/ela-articles/articles/vol18_pp420-437.pdf. Essentially, they are a system of two equations of the kind you are considering with different matrices but with the same unknowns $\lambda,\mu$. Since you have two equations in typically that setting, you get a finite number of solutions $(\lambda,\mu)$.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Gottfried's answer:
The eigencircle ${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{cart}$ or ${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{polar}$ of a linear transformation $\mathfrak{t}$ is a circle defined by all possible tuples $(s,\theta)$

where
$\theta=\angle\left(\vec{x,}\mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)\right)$ is the angle between an original vector $\vec{x}$ and its image $\mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)$ and 
$s=\frac{\|\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x})\|}{\|\vec{x}\|}$ is the scaling $s$ from the original length $\|\vec{x}\|$ to the final length $\|\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x})\|$.

${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{polar}=\left\{\left(\ s_{\vec{x}},\theta_{\vec{x}}\right)| \exists\vec{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]\ and\ \mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\left[\begin{matrix}s_{\vec{x}}&0\\0&s_{\vec{x}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&-\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\+\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]=A\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]\right\}$


${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{polar}=\left\{\left(s_{\vec{x}},\theta_{\vec{x}}\right) |\ \exists \vec{x}\ such\ that\ s_{\vec{x}}=\frac{\|\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x})\|}{\|\vec{x}\|} \ and\ \theta_{\vec{x}}=\angle(\vec{x},\mathfrak{t}(\vec{x}))\right\}$

${EC(\mathfrak{t})}_{cart}=\left\{\left(\lambda,\mu\right)|\exists\vec{x}=\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]and\ \mathfrak{t}\left(\vec{x}\right)=\left[\begin{matrix}\lambda &-\mu\\+\mu&\lambda\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]=\left[\begin{matrix}s_{\vec{x}}&0\\0&s_{\vec{x}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&-\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\+\sin{\theta_{\vec{x}}}&\cos{\theta_{\vec{x}}}\\\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}x\\y\\\end{matrix}\right]\right\}$

I think extending it to higher dimensions will result in an 'eigenball'.
But I suspect this will not be useful:
the added value of the eigencircle is the visual interpretation and derivation of properties of a linear transform in the plane.

If you want to know more about eigencircles of 2x2 matrices, visit [www.heavisidesdinner.com](https://www.heavisidesdinner.com)

[Public Geogebra example showing eigencircles](http:///https://www.geogebra.org/m/xdk5jehk)

[visualization of a point, its image and the corresponding point on the eigencircle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGGxF.png)